# How prove this inequality?

Tags: inequality

**Question:**

> let sequence $x_{i}\neq 0,i=1,2,\cdots,n$ are real numbers, show that
>   $$\left|x_{l}-\dfrac{\displaystyle\max_{1\le k\le n}|x_{k}|\min_{1\le k\le n}|x_{k}|}{x_{l}}\right|
> \le \max_{1\le k\le n}|x_{k}|-\min_{1\le k\le n}|x_{k}|,\forall l\in [1,n]$$

let
$$Q=\max_{1\le k\le n}|x_{k}|\min_{1\le k\le n}|x_{k}|$$
we consider this function
$$f(x)=\left|x-\dfrac{Q}{x}\right|$$
then How to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

First, note that if for some $l$, we have $x_l<0$, one can replace $x_l$ by $-x_l$, as your function $f(x)$ satisfy $f(-x)=f(x)$. Hence we may suppose that $x_l>0$ for all $l$. Now we can also suppose  that $0<x_1\leq x_2\leq ...\leq x_n$. We want hence prove that for all $l$ we have

$$|x_l-\frac{x_1x_n}{x_l}|\leq x_n-x_1$$
or:
 $$|x_l-\frac{x_1x_n}{x_l}|^2\leq (x_n-x_1)^2$$

and this becomes $(x_n^2-x_l^2)(x_l^2-x_1^2)\geq 0$, and we are done.